# How is the Ripple cilent bootstrapped?

Tags: ripple

When the Ripple client starts, it connects to some initial servers.

How does its find the initial list of servers it should connect to?
Is the initial list hardcoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client is configured with the server or servers it should connect to in a configuration stored on the web server that serves the client and retrieved by the client using HTTP. In the current version of the client, this can be changed from the `Options` screen. I believe this change is currently not saved but there are plans to store a list of servers in the wallet.

Comment: Something definitely gets stored locally these days. See:[link](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10039/how-can-i-recover-access-to-ripple-wallet)