# How can I recover access to Ripple wallet

Tags: ripple, ripple-client

I have been 'playing' with my account at ripple.com. Among other things I tried to access another Bitcoin issuer (server, gateway?) by typing and saving WeExchange address in Advanced, Options, Web Socket. I think I may have typed in the incorrect address.

I was logged out and when I tried to log back in, I get "loading" icon shown 'forever'. In fact, I can't even get to the login page.

All in all, I cannot access my wallet/account anymore.

What can I do now? I filed a bug report at client GitHub but am hoping I may get a response here faster, plus it is not a bad idea to have the solution documented also here.

I am using Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Can't site admins do anything about this incessant downvoting with no arguments?

Comment: You don't need to connect your client to a different server to use a different gateway. One has nothing to do with the other. When you say "when I tried to log back in", what *precisely* do you mean?

Comment: Means: typed ripple.com in Chrome address bar, on page that shows clicked on **Open Wallet** in the top right corner, then on next page **Existing users, access your wallet here**, clicked on `wallet here`. The next page shows loading icon and stays like that. However, I have found a solution by editing local storage of that page with Chrome Developer tools. I could log in again after I edited websocket_ip and set it back to s1.ripple.com. I'll leave bug report [GitHub link](https://github.com/rippleFoundation/ripple-client/issues/441) because many users wouldn't be able to figure this out.

Comment: **A gateway runs a Ripple server, rippled, to promote the health of the network and to have their own a trusted interface to the Ripple network.** per
[wiki](https://ripple.com/wiki/Gateway_Integration_Manual) so it is really not correct to say that one has nothing to do with another. Unless something changed in that respect?

Comment: That's how the gateway itself accesses the Ripple network. It has nothing whatsoever to do with how other people access either the Ripple network or the gateway.

Comment: I see (I think). Since gateway can be a shop down the street it doesn't necessarily have http(s) address and http(s) address of its ripple server doesn't necessarily serve gateway clients.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a valid client usability problem whatever I was thinking I may be connecting to when changing Web socket address.